# How to convert cell type number to string in XLSX? For Handling Date format

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, xlsx

I'm using **npm i xlsx** for reading xlsx file. so my questions here ... in my xlsx sheet i given **Indian standard date (DD/MM/YYYY)** like 24/09/2020 so it's giving same value... if I give 03/09/2020 it's giving number 43898 like this. set **cellDates:true** it's giving 2020-03-09T00:00:00.000Z so here **date take as a month**.. I don't want like this .i want same string 03 /09/2020..
my code is here

```
var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames; 
var wSheet = workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[0]]; 
let xlsxDate = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(wSheet, { "defval": null, raw: true });
 xlsxDate.forEach(function (val, index) {
       console.log(val)
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

Excel's date format is a bit different. When you write a date value like "08.09.2020" it will parse it to a number (like 43898). When you write a date value to Excel, it will calculate how many days passed from 01.01.1900 to the given date.

So the number you get (43898) is just the number of days passed between 01.01.1900 and 09.09.2020.

Edit your sheet_to_json method like this:

`XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(wSheet,{"defval": null, raw:true, dateNF "dd/mm/yyyy"})`

You basically need to add `dateNF : "dd/mm/yyyy"` to your options object.